# function is not getting called from a click function in angular 5

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular5

Hi Guys i'm stuck with a small issue in angular 5, I'm trying to call a common session check method which is imported from a common ts file, i'm using the session check method on load of the page and on click of logout button to redirect the user to login page. but on load of the page it works fine, but on click of a button it gives an error of undefined, Please help thanks in advance.

Dashboard
[image]
Imported
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`this` inside `function() { ... }` definition does not refer to your component, but to that function context. Use arrow function so `this` context will remain bound to your component:

```
logout() {
  session.signOut().then(() => {
    this.s.checkIfSignedIn();
  });
}
```

Also you should remove the `var` keyword when declaring class variable `u`.

Bonus advices:

- care about your editor/linter warnings (to suppress errors when accessing global objects like `gapi`, declare that first like this: `declare const gapi: any;`)
- care about code indenting
- try to make your variable names descriptive, do not use names like `a` or `u`, again so you do not get lost in the code so easily (btw you have `utils` variable there too, maybe you should use that instead of defining new one called `u`...)

Answer (score 0):

You are declaring it with `var` and calling it with `this`. It's not a property of the component, that's why it's not working.

Answer (score 0):

You have a different scope inside the promise.

```
logout() {
 let self = this;
 var session = gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance();
 session.signOut().then( function() {
   localStorage.clear();
   self.s.checkIfSignedIn();
  });
}
```